# SwiftUI : stack overlapping elements horizontally?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to stack overlapping elements horizontally, like this:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
struct StackedElementsView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .purple]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { i in
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        colors[i]
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                    }
                    .offset(x: CGFloat(i) * 25)
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 24)
            Color.purple
                .frame(width: 100, height: 44)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}

struct StackedElementsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackedElementsView()
    }
}
```

I have an issue with this, the purple rectangle overlaps the circles and I don't know why.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.offset` just changes where the view draws, but doesn't change the frame which is why the rectangle draws further left than you expect.

One way to fix this is to add appropriate leading padding to the rectangle:

```
Color.purple
    .frame(width: 100, height: 44)
    .padding(.leading, CGFloat(colors.count - 1) * 25)
```

---

**Alternate solution**

Instead of using `.offset`, use a `Color.clear` view in an `HStack` to provide the spacing needed:

```
ForEach(0..<colors.count) { i in
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.clear
                .frame(width: CGFloat(i) * 25, height: 44)
            colors[i]
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The alternate approach is perfect.

Answer (score 9):

Here would be a more intuitive solution. You could instead use negative spacing and have only `HStack`s:

[image]

```
struct StackedElementsView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .purple]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack(spacing: -25) {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { i in
                    colors[i]
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                }
            }
            
            Color.purple
                .frame(width: 100, height: 44)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.leading, 24)
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need `-19` as the spacing?  `0` spacing would offset the circles by their width `44`, so to achieve `25` you'd need to subtract `19`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose vacawama solution but yours could work too.

Comment: is there a way to reverse the hstack element arrangement? Like the red circle on top, blue below that followed by purple.